# Product > Archive Failed – Why? Where are errors reported in Xcode 7.3.1?

Tags: xcode, build, xcode7

In Xcode 7.3.1 my existing app, already shipped in App Store, now fails when I choose `Product` > `Archive`.

No errors appear on the console. No errors flagged red in the sidebar.

**How can I get a report on the errors causing the Archive to fail?**

---

By the way, I have already tried restarting Xcode 7.3.1, restarting the Mac (virtual machine actually), choosing `Product` > `Clean` and choosing (with Option key pressed) `Product` > `Clean Build Folder`. None of that helped.

Choosing `Product` > `Build` succeeds.